# Store values within recursion to use later MATLAB

Tags: matlab, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive multigrid algorithm in MATLAB.

I need to store the values  of v and TC at each of the levels I'm going through to use when I'm no longer in the recursion by just calling them, in a similar way v{L} would have worked for example if I did a for loop.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
function x = vcycle1d(n, x, b, T, w, levels)

    x = damped_jacobiM(w, x, T, b, 10^-7, 3);

    res = b - T*x;

    k = log2(n+1);
    N = 2^(k-1)-1;
    RE = zeros(N,n);
    for i = 1:N
        RE(i,2*i-1:2*i+1) = [1 2 1]; 
    end
    RE = RE/4;        
    II = 2*RE';
    TC = RE * T * II;

    v = zeros(N, 1);
    for i = 1:N
        v(i) = (res(2*i-1) + 2*res(2*i) + res(2*i+1))/4;
    end

    if levels ~= 1
        err= vcycle1d(N, zeros(length(v), 1), v, TC, w, levels-1);
    else
        err = TC\v;
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

Option 1: Use a persistent variable. This allows you to store details in a variable that retains values between calls.

The pros of this are that you can use it to "remember" all sorts of things from previous calls. 
The cons of this are that you'll need to manage that memory in some sensible way.

Option 2: Use additional, optional, inputs.

```
function x = vcycle1d(n, x, b, T, w, levels, varargin)

if nargin  == 7
    priordetails = varargin{1};
end
currentdetails = ... ;
    ....

err= vcycle1d(N, zeros(length(v), 1), v, TC, w, levels-1, currentdetails);
```